# Access to tfidf values in gensim

Tags: python, tf-idf, gensim, corpus

I want to find N words with greatest TFIDF value for each document

I'm using gensim with a corpus to compute tfidf values:

```
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(mmcorpus)
corpus_tfidf = tfidf[mmcorpus]
```

Then, I would like to get tf-idf of given words in each document of the corpus
By looking in my corpus_tfidf object, I see a corpus part with an index array of size 417 (which is the size of my corpus), but I doesn't find documentation to help me to get TFIDF of a word in a document of the corpus
Note: the answer of the question "Getting TF-IDF Scores Of Words Using Gensim" doesn't really solves the problem; it gives an unique value for each word

===EDIT===

From other sample codes, I've tried with success the following code (surely not as Pythonic than it can be):

```
for doc in corpus_tfidf: 
    d = {} 
    for id, value in doc: 
        if value>0: 
            d[corpus.dictionary.get(id)] = value
```

but I can't explain or document why I can do 'for doc in corpus_tfidf'and get something useful, corpus_tfidf is not clearly iterable and as it is, what define the objects obtained from each iteration?
Then, a subsequent question is: how can I find the source associated with the doc variable? I will create a separate question about that